# Delete Confirmation when click on link

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have this code inside a `while` loop for fetching data from the database. I want to show a confirmation popup when the `Delete` link is clicked.

```
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row['serial_no'] . "'>Delete</a></td>";
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Use `confirm` for that

Comment: What have you tried? Can you not just use javascript to detect whenever you click on a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out `confirm` function from JavaScript, learn jQuery as fast as possible and try to seperate javascript from html ;).

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

```
<td>
    <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['serial_no'] ?>" id="a_id">
        Delete
    </a>
</td>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('td a#a_id').click(function() {
            return confirm("Are You sure that You want to delete this?");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: W3Schools is not a very good resource to learn JavaSCript from. See **http://w3fools.com/** for why.

Answer (score 1):

add `onClick` attribute for anchor link and call the function on it. Or simply show `confirm`.

```
<a onClick = "confirm ('Are You Sure?')"
```

**Complete Example**

```
function disp_confirm()
{
    var r=confirm("Press a button!")
    if (r==true)
    {
        alert("You pressed OK!")
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You pressed Cancel!")
    }
}

<a onclick="disp_confirm()"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function DeleteClick(serial_no)
{
if(confirm('Are you sure to delete ' + serial_no + '?'))
{
    alert('Data deleted');
    return true;
}
return false;
}

echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row['serial_no'] . "' onclick="return 
 DeleteClick(\''. $row['serial_no'].'\')">Delete</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row['serial_no'] . "' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');\">Delete</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code,hope it will work-

```
<td>
    <a href="#" onclick="conf("delete.php?id=".<?php echo $row['serial_no']; ?>.")">
        Delete
    </a>
</td>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function conf(str) {
       if(confirm("Your Message") == true){ location.replace(str);}
    }
</script>
```

and in the delete.php page-just grab the id from url and run the delete query.